# How can I add .attr('colspan', '100') dynamically if only one visible table cell in a row?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, html-table

So as the title suggests, I'd like to dynamically add `colspan="100"` to any lonely cell in a table row using jquery.

I'm using a wordpress plugin to add a table to a page, but it doesn't allow for the use of colspan, so I am hiding any empty cells with jquery.
The problem occurs when there is only one cell being used in a row. I'd like it to span `100%`.

I need to be able to count each visible cell in each row and if there is only one, add `.attr('colspan', '100')` to that one cell so that it fills the row.

Any ideas? Thanks

This is what I am generating with wordpress.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.curriculum table tr').each(function() {

    $('td').each(function() {
      var cellText = $.trim($(this).text());
      var $cellExp = $(this).closest('td').prev();

      if (cellText.length == 0) {
        $(this).hide();
        $cellExp.attr('colspan', '2');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="curriculum">
  <table class="table  table-responsive">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to add an entire empty row if there is only one visible cell or do you want to make this visible cell gets entire row?

Comment: Yeah, so if the row contains one cell with information, I want to remove all empty cells in that row and expand the filled row with colspan,100

Comment: Added solution. Can you check this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `colspan = 100` is not a good solution at first. Counting max td count then using it as colspan may be a better idea. If you don't want to hide other cells when there is more then 1 visible cell in a row, you can easly modify this code to achieve it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var maxTdCount = 0;
  $('.curriculum table tr').each(function() {
    $('td').each(function() {
      var cellText = $.trim($(this).text());

      if (cellText.length == 0) {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
    if($(this).find("td:visible").length > maxTdCount)
    {    maxTdCount = $(this).find("td").length;}
  });
  $('.curriculum table tr').each(function() {
  if($(this).find("td:visible").length == 1)
    {
     $(this).find("td").attr("colspan", maxTdCount);
    }
    });
});
```

```css
td{border:1px solid black}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="curriculum">
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
  <td></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: GREAT! That coupled with the script I wrote works just as I want it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is a script.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.curriculum table tr').each(function () {
           $('td').each(function () {
            var cellText = $.trim($(this).text());

            if (cellText.length == 0) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
           });
          if ($(this).children("td").length == 1) {
            $(this).children("td").attr("colspan", "100")
        }
        });
    });
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/smitraval27/pen/GxmPKe)

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately this is adding the colspan,100 to every cell and not just the cells that are on their own in the row.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Its working fine now. Please check. @MarkFeltwell There was a mistake of ";" after if statement. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would start from all cells that are followed by an empty cell and then remove any empty cells that follow, whilst adding the colspan (comments in code):

```js
$('td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).next().text().trim() === ''; // get all tds that have an empty cell after them
}).each(function() {
  var $original = $(this); // get the original cell

  if (!$original.hasClass('remove')) { // check if the cell has already been marked for removal
    var counter = 1,
      $item = $original;

    do {
      if ($item.next().text().trim() === '') {
        // next cell is empty, increment colspan and reset do...while for next cell
        counter++;
        $item = $item.next().addClass('remove');
      }
    } while ($item.next().length && $item.next().text().trim() === '');

    $original.attr('colspan', counter); // set the colspan on the first cell
  }
});

$('.remove').remove();

// merge any previous empty cells
$('td').filter(function() {
  $prev = $(this).prev();
  return $prev.length && $prev.text().trim() === ''; // get all tds that have an empty cell before them - should only be ones that start the row
}).each(function() {
  var $original = $(this),
    $prev = $original.prev();
 
  var colspan = getColspan($original) + getColspan($prev); 
  $original.attr('colspan', colspan);
  $prev.remove();
});

function getColspan($elem) {
  var attr = $elem.attr('colspan');

  if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
    return parseInt(attr);
  }

  return 1;
}
```

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="curriculum">
  <table class="table  table-responsive">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```